# USB to Ethernet in Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, dell, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 13. As the computer does not have an Ethernet port, I purchased a USB to Ethernet adapter (IcyBox IB-AC509).

It worked fine until recently, when I did an update, and then stopped working. When I use `lsusb`, the adapter is not recognized at all. I tried installing the drivers from [here](http://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=driverdetail&PItemID=136), but nothing changed. If you could help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back the update and seeing if it works again? You can try selecting "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in Grub, loading a previous kernel and see if it comes back. This is not a full-on solution but it can help figure out if it was the system update or not. Also, out of curiosity, does `ifconfig` turn up anything?

Comment: Could you please make sure that the adapter is plugged in correctly into the USB port of your computer, run `lsusb` and include its output in your question? If the adapter isn't listed it may help to try other USB ports. Thanks.

Comment: @glenabdelnoor and  @DavidFoerster  are right. To troubleshoot this load the previous kernel with the vendor driver installed and include the `lsusb` output to verify the device is detected and to know the VID/PID.

Comment: Have you checked the adapter on another computer? Are you sure the adapter itself is OK?